# PyQt5 GUI with Raspberry Pi Hardware

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, gpio, raspberry-pi4

I am writing a code for object testing using basler camera and created an PyQt5 based GUI for it. My GUI works fine but now i have to integrate external hardware for it. for. ex. I have to select and object from GUI then i will press an external switch after that focus light will turn on capture an Image and compare it with given width condition and display the output on GUI i.e. which job is selected and it is matched or not.

when i press the switch my GUI freezes and i don't get the result on GUI screen.
Please help me if i am doing something wrong

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
from pypylon import pylon
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QComboBox
from RPi import GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

class Receipe(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        combo = QComboBox(self)
        combo.addItem("A")
        combo.addItem("B")
        combo.addItem("C")
        combo.move(50, 50)
        self.qlabel = QLabel(self)
        self.qlabel.move(50, 16)
        combo.activated[str].connect(self.onChanged)
        self.status = QLabel(self)
        self.status.move(50, 86)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 320, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle("Receipe Selection")
        self.show()
        
        
        
        self.light_switch = 16
        self.relay_light = 8
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.setup(self.light_switch, GPIO.IN)
        GPIO.setup(self.relay_light, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(self.relay_light, False)

    def onChanged(self, text):
        self.qlabel.setText("Type"+" "+text+" "+"Job Is Selected")
        self.qlabel.adjustSize()
        
        #mention coondition here
        img = Camera().frame
        print ("Capture Frame")
        while True:
            if GPIO.input(self.light_switch) == 0:
                print ("Switch Pressed")
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(self.relay_light,True)
                time.sleep(1)
                process = ImgProcess()
                print ("Process Image")
                GPIO.output(self.relay_light, False)
                result = process.process(text,img)
                print(result)              
                if result == True:
                    print("in result")
                    self.status.setText("Ok")
                else:
                    self.status.setText("Not Ok")


class Camera:
    def __init__(self):
        self.serial_no = "23252513"
        self.ExposureTime = 4000
        self.device_id = None
        devices = [i.GetSerialNumber() for i in pylon.TlFactory.GetInstance().EnumerateDevices()]
        if self.serial_no in devices:
                self.device_id = "23252513"
        else:
            print('Camera not found')

        info = pylon.DeviceInfo()
        info.SetSerialNumber(self.serial_no)
        self.camera = pylon.InstantCamera(pylon.TlFactory.GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice(info))
        # self.camera = pylon.InstantCamera(pylon.TlFactory.CreateDevice(self.device_id))
        self.camera.Open()
        self.camera.ExposureAuto.SetValue('Off')
        self.camera.ExposureTimeRaw.SetValue(self.ExposureTime)
        self.camera.StartGrabbing(pylon.GrabStrategy_LatestImageOnly)


    @property
    def frame(self):
        if self.device_id is not None:
            converter = pylon.ImageFormatConverter()
            converter.OutputPixelFormat = pylon.PixelType_BGR8packed
            converter.OutputBitAlignment = pylon.OutputBitAlignment_MsbAligned

            while self.camera.IsGrabbing():
                try:
                    try:
                        grabResult = self.camera.RetrieveResult(5000, pylon.TimeoutHandling_ThrowException)
                    except pylon.TimeoutHandling_ThrowException as e:
                        print(e)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)

                    if grabResult.GrabSucceeded():
                        frame = converter.Convert(grabResult).GetArray()
                        return frame
                    else:
                        print('Camera not found')
                    grabResult.Release()
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
            else:
                print('Camera not found')
            self.camera.StopGrabbing()

    def close(self):
        self.camera.Close()

class ImgProcess:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        self.relay_ok = 10
        self.relay_faulty = 12
        GPIO.setup(self.relay_ok, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(self.relay_faulty, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(self.relay_ok, False)
        GPIO.output(self.relay_faulty, False)
        
    def process(self,txt,img):
        self.data = txt
        result = ""
        status = True
        oimg = img
        gimg = cv2.cvtColor(oimg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        bw_img = cv2.inRange(gimg, 0, 130)
        kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
        erode_img = cv2.dilate(bw_img, kernel=kernel, iterations=1)
        cntr, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(erode_img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        cntr = sorted(cntr, key=cv2.contourArea)
        job_cntr = cntr[-1]
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(job_cntr)
        cv2.rectangle(oimg, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        # print(x, y, w, h)

        if w < 700:
            result = "A"
            print("TYPE-A Job Is Detected")
        elif (w > 800) and (w < 900):
            result = "B"
            print("TYPE-B Job Is Detected")
        elif (w > 900) and (w < 1000):
            result = "C"
            print("TYPE-C Job Is Detected")
        else:
            print("INVALID JOB")

        if result == self.data:
            GPIO.output(self.relay_ok,True)
            time.sleep(1)
            GPIO.output(self.relay_ok,False)
            print("Ok")
            
        else:
            GPIO.output(self.relay_faulty,True)
            time.sleep(1)
            GPIO.output(self.relay_faulty,False)
            print("Faulty")
            status = False
        
        return status


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    recp = Receipe()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to read. Any chance you can reduce it to a minimal example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I would advice to use PDB or something similar to walk through your code to check where it freezes.

Comment: @Ludo21South can you please elaborate what is PDB ?

Comment: @101 my GUI code stuck at onchanged function

Comment: Of course. PDB is the python debugger (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) which allows you to step through code and allows you to inspect variables which might give you more insight into what is going on in the code. It's a super useful tool which I discovered is unfortunately not used as much.

Comment: @Ludo21South Thank you. i have tried that too but not getting what i want. is there an issue with while loop and PyQT

Comment: Well, in general you should avoid while loops in gui, for the exact reason you have here. Apparently the exit condition for the loop is never reached? Two ways to go about that; 1. make sure that an exit condition is always reached (even if it does not satisfy the end result). 2. work with asynchronous calls, for example with a message queue.

Comment: The reason is exactly what Ludo21South points out: UI frameworks should **never** have blocking functions (such as `time.sleep`) or blocking loops within their main thread, otherwise those will make the ui unresponsive and unable to update itself, and that's because they prevent the event queue to be processed. In order to do parallel processing *and* access the UI, QThreads must be used along with custom signales (as **NO** direct access to UI elements is allowed from external threads)

Comment: Thank you @musicamante for your reply but if possible can you share an example or source of the same  so that i can work on ,my code according

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this in def onChanged(self, text)

```
if GPIO.input(self.light_switch) == 0:
```

If you do this your app will frezze.
If you want to work with GPIO pins, use gpiozero library, in your case you will have to use the object Button

check out this:
https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#button